# Convert an XML response to JSON in Flutter?

Tags: json, xml, flutter

I am receiving an API response in XML format in my Flutter app and I need to convert it to JSON to process the data.
I'm already using [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) for sending data to api's in xml format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Dart Http XML rest convert to Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124231/flutter-dart-http-xml-rest-convert-to-json)

Comment: Thank you @Monasha. That's helpful

Comment: "I need to convert it to JSON to process the data" I'm not a Dart developer but that doesn't really make any sense: typically in a programming language you process data that's been serialized to a text format like XML or JSON by parsing it into *data structures in your programming language*, not by converting it to a different text format.

Comment: Actually I have to convert response to a dart model, that's what I meant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import xml file to dart object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65799906/how-to-import-xml-file-to-dart-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert an XML response to JSON by using the xml2json package. Here are the steps to do it:

1. Add the xml2json package to your pubspec.yaml file and run flutter
   pub get to install it.

   ```
   dependencies:
   xml2json: ^4.2.0
   ```
2. Import the xml2json package in your Dart file.

   ```
   final xmlString = "<person><name>John</name><age>30</age></person>";
   final xml2json = Xml2Json();
   xml2json.parse(xmlString);
   final jsonString = xml2json.toParker();
   final jsonObject = json.decode(jsonString);
   ```